# Why do we access enum values with ::

Tags: c++, enums, language-design

My question is simple and maybe stupid.
Whats the design decision behind accessing enum members via `::` in C++, when we access struct and class members via `.`

Comment: :: is the scope resolution operator across the board. Having a namespace or type on the left is consistent, including enums.

Comment: @chris: Answers go in the answer section mate

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Honestly, I would have put more effort into an answer. It was one quick reason without any elaboration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`::` is used when the left operand is the name of a type or namespace and `.` is used when the left operand is an object. For the same reason static members of structs or classes are also accessed using `::`.